# why require(), include(), include_once() needed in PHP?

Tags: php

I don't understand the need for require(), include(), include_once() statements in PHP.

I feel strongly that require_once() is all you need in PHP.

In C/C++,  there is just #include().
In Java, there is just import().

In PHP,  if include('xyz.php') gives just warning messages but the rest of the script works, this means that this include('xyx.php') statement is not needed in the first place.

I thought that  when you include something in a script, it should be included just once.
If same file is accidentally included multiple times, there should some kind of 'duplicate' error messages during run time. If it does not give such error messages, there is a serious flaw with the language.

Can someone tell me why require(), include(), include_once() must exist in PHP when require_once() itself is sufficient?

Thanks

Comment: C, C++ and Java compile all (specified) sources in the object/or-other-unit file during compilation. php is not a compiled language so you need to help it with what files it need to load.

Comment: Can your php scripts can be complete with the usage of require_once()? Please provide an example where require(), include() or Include_once() is needed in place of require_once().  That is the point of this question.

Answer (score 4):

Read php.net and the excerpts is given below.

**require**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.

**include_once**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

> The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns TRUE. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.
>
> include_once may be used in cases where the same file might be
>   included and evaluated more than once during a particular execution of
>   a script, so in this case it may help avoid problems such as function
>   redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc.

Comment: I read this and it does not explain my question.   Can your php scripts can be complete with the usage of require_once()? Please provide an example where require(), include() or Include_once() is needed in place of require_once(). That is the point of this question.

Comment: The excerpts given above from the php manual is self explanatory. What do you mean by "complete"?

Comment: Lets say, in PHP, there is only require_once() statement.  Lets assume include(), include_once() nor require() do not exist.  Can your PHP application work with using just require_once()?

Comment: Yes. It depends on two things: 1. what type of error level you want, when you have issues with reading the included file (choose between require or include) and 2. Whether you want to reduce the php script execution overhead due to repeatedly calling the external file (choose between either include_once or require_once and include or require). Your decision of using one the these commands will be based on these criteria. It is subject to the php developer. The flexibility of fine tuning a php application using one of these commands may be the reason why these commands exist....